# WPF Applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed is always return false

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce, setup-deployment

i used ClickOnce publish to deploy my WPF applicaiton

when i try to update manually

the **`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed is always return false`** so it doesnt check for the updated. it cant able to find the currentdeployment settings

am using the below method to update manually
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Answer (score 6):

IsNetworkDeployed will only be true if the application is launched from its deployment url (.xbap).  The only reason IsNetworkDeployed would return false in a deployed application is if accessing ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment throws an exception....

So to more deeply investigate your problem, you should be able to do something like this:

```
 try
 {
      string foo = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
 }
```

Comment: it throws some exception

{System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application identity does not match the application already installed.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment..ctor(String fullAppId)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()

Comment: Found more comprehensive answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/wpf/thread/f1ec20c8-9225-4e5d-903a-434e33aff349)

Comment: If you don't like the exception handling strategy, you could test whether `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` contains ``\AppData\``